# Is there any way to fix this: Expected name at line 45 column 7 path $.client[0].services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Got this error code when trying to build on android studio.

> Expected name at line 45 column 7 path $.client[0].services

Where is the error located.  Kindly assist with this

Below attached is my google-services.json file. If that might help

```json
 {
   "project_info": {
     ...
   },
   "client": [
     {
         "client_info": {
           ...
         },
         "oauth_client": [
           ...
         ],
         "api_key": [
           ...
         ],
         "services": {
           ...
         },
       {                      
         "client_info": {
           ...
         },
```

Comment: I modified your post because I believe it contained information that might have been sensitive. You should consider deleting this ASAP if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the error is at line 45 column 7

```json
 1: {
 2:   "project_info": {
...     ...
 7:   },
 8:   "client": [
 9:     {
10:         "client_info": {
...           ...
15:         },
16:         "oauth_client": [
...           ...
29:         ],
30:         "api_key": [
...           ...
34:         ],
35:         "services": {
...           ...
44:         },
45:       {                      <== error is here
46:         "client_info": {
...           ...
51:         },
```

The indentations are a bit inconsistent, but since line 46 looks like a second instance of line 10, I believe the problem is that the `services` property is supposed to be the last property of that `client` object, so the `,` should have been a `},` on a line by itself.

```json
35:         "services": {
...           ...
44:         }
new       },
45:       {
46:         "client_info": {
```

That ends the object started on line 9, and line 45 then starts a second object for the array started in line 8.